# Display product thumbnail in Woocommerce email notifications

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, templates, hooks

I've overridden Woocommerce template file `email-order-details` to display the product thumbnail in customer's email:

```
<?php
    echo wc_get_email_order_items( $order, array( // WPCS: XSS ok.
        'show_sku'      => $sent_to_admin,
        'show_image'    => true,
        'image_size'    => array( 100, 100 ),
        'plain_text'    => $plain_text,
        'sent_to_admin' => $sent_to_admin,
    ) );
?>
```

But only white space is displayed in the received email.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use `woocommerce_email_order_items_args` filter.
It can be done this way:

```
function add_product_thumbnail_to_wc_emails( $args ) {
    $args['show_image'] = true;
    $args['image_size'] = array( 100, 100 );
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_items_args', 'add_product_thumbnail_to_wc_emails' );
```

The code has to be placed to functions.php